# Move up in directory structure

Tags: python, file, directory, relative-path

Say I am running a Python script in `C:\temp\templates\graphics`. I can get the current directory using `currDir = os.getcwd()`, but how can I use relative path to move up in directories and execute something in `C:\temp\config` (note: this folder will not always be in `C:\`)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If this is `/config` for your Python program, consider making it part of the module rather than faffing around with the working dir.

Comment: Are you looking for `os.chdir('..')`?

Comment: Oh, I just tried this. This looks promising. So, I can use this to move up and then do os.getcwd() again to get the directory. thanks

Comment: There are a range of options supplied by [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) that might meet your needs. I'm unclear what your needs actually are but perhaps `os.path.relpath(path[, start])` might be useful?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/user/code'
>>> os.chdir('..')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/user'
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly clear what you are trying to do, here are two alternatives:

To change your process's current working directory "up" the path:

```
os.chdir('../../config')
```

Or, to open a file using a relative pathname:

```
with open('../../config/my_config.ini') as cfg_file:
    pass
```

Of course, if you do change your current working directory, then your `open()` argument should change, also:

```
os.chdir('../../config')
with open('my_config.ini') as cfg_file:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
`os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))), "config")`